# How to solve this Key error on a pandas dataframe after 1414th element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello my dataframe named CAR has 2213 rows however whenever I try to access a row that is after the 1413th element I get an error. So far I haven't found similar errors on the site but my dataframe is quite standard (no Na,only string or integers, size 7 by 2213) so I have no idea how to solve this problem.

```
CAR['Code RS'][1414]
len(CAR)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-0cf1ffa9a735> in <module>
----> 1 CAR['Code RS'][1414]
      2 len(CAR)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    869         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
    870         try:
--> 871             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    872 
    873             if not is_scalar(result):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4403         k = self._convert_scalar_indexer(k, kind="getitem")
   4404         try:
-> 4405             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
   4406         except KeyError as e1:
   4407             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1414
```

I'm using Jupyter notebook if that helps.
Thanks.

Comment: Try resetting indices: `CAR = CAR.reset_index(drop=True)`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Do you know what was the problem?

Comment: I submitted an answer. I would appreciate if you mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the indices of your `DataFrame`:

```py
CAR = CAR.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

To demonstrate the issue, here is an example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':[6,7]})
```

```
   a  b
0  1  6
1  2  7
```

```py
df2 = df.copy()
```

```
   a  b
0  1  6
1  2  7
```

Let's concatenate them. Look closely at the indices of the resulting `DataFrame`:

```py
df3 = pd.concat([df, df2])
```

```
   a  b
0  1  6
1  2  7
0  1  6
1  2  7
```

We can fix that by resetting the indices:

```py
df4 = df3.reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
   a  b
0  1  6
1  2  7
2  1  6
3  2  7
```

This is just a test case scenario, there may be other reasons for this problem, such as:

```py
df4.drop([2])
```

```
   a  b
0  1  6
1  2  7
3  2  7
```